# Entering name with aligned position/address below

Tags: horizontal-alignment, article

What is the best/logical way to enter someone's position and address below their name and have them left aligned with their name when a document/letter is addressed to them?

For example, if I want to address a letter like the following:

```
To: John Smith
    Position here
    Address here
```

Here I have manually typed in spaces so the first word of the lines below the name are aligned with the first word of the name, but I don't want to guess the spacing in my document every time.

I don't want:

```
To: John Smith
Position here
Location here
```

I'm assuming I am missing something basic...any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that there are classes for writing letters, the job of aligning material is most easily achieved with a `tabular`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{ }l@{}}
To: & John Smith \\
 & Position Here\\
 & Address here
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

or maybe

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

To:
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
John Smith \\
Position here\\
Address here
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's as simple as that `:-)`

Answer (score 6):

Here shown with a `\Longunderstack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
To: \Longunderstack[l]{John Smith \\ Position Here\\ Address Here}
\end{document}
```

[image]